# Making GL_POINTS look like a 3D Rectangle

Tags: webgl

Suppose one has an array of GL_POINTS and wants to make each appear to have a distinct "height" or "depth", so instead of appearing like a flat scatter of squares they appear to be a scatter of 3D rectangles / right rectangular prisms.

Is there a technique in WebGL that will allow one to achieve this effect? One could of course use vertices that actually articulate those 3D rectangles, but my goal is to optimize for performance as I have ~100,000 of these rectangles to render, and I thought points would be the best primitive to use.

Right now I am thinking one could probably use a series of point sprites each with varying depth, then assign each point the sprite that corresponds most closely with the desired depth (effectively quantizing the depth data field). But is there a way to keep the depth field continuous?

Any pointers on this question would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just modulate `gl_PointSize` by the distance to the camera? The caveats gman outlined still apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience `POINTS` are not faster than making your own vertices. Also, if you use [instanced drawing](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-instanced-drawing.htm) you can get away with almost the same amount of data. You need one quad and then position, width, and height for each rectangle. Not sure instancing is as fast as just making all the vertices though. Might depend on the GPU/driver

As **point**ed out  in many other Q&As on points, the maximum point size is GPU/driver specific and allowed to be as low as 1 pixel. There are plenty of GPUs that only allow size >= 256 pixels (no idea why) and a few with only size >= 64. Yet another reason to not use `POINTS`

Otherwise though, `POINTS` always draw a square so you'd have to draw a square large enough that contains your rectangle and then in the fragment shader, `discard` the pixels outside of the rectangle.

That's unlikely to be good for speed though. Every pixel of the square will still need to be evaluated by the fragment shader which is slower than drawing a rectangle with vertices since then those pixels outside the rectangle are not even considered. Further, using `discard` in a shader is often slower than not using it. This is because, for example, things like setting the depth buffer, if there is no discard nothing needs to be checked, the depth buffer can be updated unconditionally separate from the shader. With discard the depth buffer can't be updated until the GPU knows if the shader kept or discarded the fragment.

As for making them appear 3D I'm not sure what you mean. Effectively points are just like drawing a square quad so you can put anything you want on that square. The majority of shaders on shadertoy can be adapted to draw themselves on points. I wouldn't recommend it as it would likely be slow but just pointing out that it's just a quad. Draw [a texture](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/49emupqd/) on them, draw a [procedural texture](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/4k5tov3s/) on them, draw a [solid color](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/Lyp4twxq/) on them, draw a [procedural snail](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/Lyp4twxq/) on them.

Another possible solution is you can apply a [normal map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping) to the quad and then do lighting calculations on those normals so each quad will have the correct lighting for its position relative to your light(s)

Comment: Thanks @gman, you continue to teach me so much! The idea that "using discard in a shader is often slower than not using it" seemed impossible until you explained it. You're probably right--instancing is probably the cleanest way to do this.